# validate mustache tag value from json file

Tags: jquery, mustache

Hi I havent been able to find how to validate a tag before displaying it, for instance: if I have a JSON file lets says this values:

```
{ "weeks":
  [
    {
      "monday800": "no",
      "monday830": "available",
      "tuesday800": "available",
      "tuesday830": "no",
      "name": "TEST"
    }
  ]
}
```

I bring the value like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.get("data.json",function(data){
        var template = $("#tpl").html();
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template,data);
        console.log ();
        $("#information").html(html);
    });
});
```

Now what I want to do is:
     `if {{monday830}} == "available" then display {{name}}`

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out, but i have to change the field from "no" to "":
{{#monday800}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>
{{/monday800}}
{{^monday800}}
  ---
{{/monday800}} 
so in this scenario if there is blank it will not display the name
however still the question if I want to validate that tag to an specific value?
Any information, will be super appreciate it
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible in mustache as its logic less. Use  [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com) instead.

If you still want to achieve this in mustache then:

You can not use any if statement but you can check  if  anything exist or its value is true.

if this case you have to update json like:

```
{ "weeks": [    {
      "monday800": "no",
      "monday830": "available",
      "monday830_available": true, // you have to add another property here
      "tuesday800": "available",
      "tuesday830": "no",
      "name": "TEST"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Then you can check

```
{{#monday830_available}}
     ..............
{{/monday830_available}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with the same problem as the author described in a comment on the question and according to the `mustache` library, you cannot do it. There is an [issue](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/599) about it. 
But this problem is widespread and there is a fork to help you.
Here is the [link](https://github.com/ScottFreeCode/mustache.js). 
It works like should.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18466620)

Comment: Changed it. Thank you

Comment: Thanks are yours sir :)