# How to validate mustache template with mustache.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, mustache

I'm using the module `ejs` for validating ejs template and variables that come from the admin dashboard:

```
try {
  resolve(ejs.render(template, variables))
} catch (error) {
  reject(error)
}
```

And if there are some issues with this template, it throws an error, and I can send it to the client.

Also, I have a mustache template to validate. I'm using the same approach:

```
try {
  resolve(mustache.render(template, variables))
} catch (error) {
  reject(error)
}
```

But `mustache` doesn't throw an error at all, and if there is no variable, it just replaces it with an empty string.

How can I solve this issue? Need to validate templates properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution in this [fork](https://github.com/ScottFreeCode/mustache.js) of the library. 
Thanks to [Scott](https://github.com/ScottFreeCode) it works like should.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), there is no way to have it throw errors on undefined variables, [here is an open issue](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/599). This seems to be fine according to the [Mustache specification](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html).

> By default a variable "miss" returns an empty string. This can usually be configured in your Mustache library.

So if you really need to validate that there are no undefined variables, you're going to have to use another JS library for Mustache (if there is any, I'm not sure), or hope that they add the feature.

Comment: I know about docs, no questions to this. I guessed maybe this issue is widespread and there is a possible decision for this.

Comment: And it is widespread. 
Here is the same topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269415/validate-mustache-tag-value-from-json-file/48169525

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still needing a solution for this and doesn't want to/can't use another templatinh library I've created a small package to add data validation to Mustache: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache-validator